# Install seems to hang, but I'm not sure

Tags: installation, dvd

I am trying to install Ubuntu on an old computer that had Windows XP on it.

After struggling with why it wouldn't boot from the DVD, I ran across the solution where you typed help into the prompt  and that worked for me.

I took most of the defaults and chose to overwrite XP and only install Ubuntu.

It was painfully slow.  I attribute that to booting from the DVD.  At one point after I had answered all the questions and the bar at the bottom said "copying files" for quite a while, the install window simply disappeared.  My mouse icon is still a swirly and has been for hours.  The menu bar at the top of the screen is not functional so I can't even gracefully shutdown.

If I do shut down with a control/alt/delete and try to start without the DVD, it hangs and never comes close to starting.

I've repeated these steps several times.  What is going on????

Thanks,
dogulas

Answer (score 2):

I've recently had installation problems during a 12.04 installation process on an older machine. I found that installing from the "alternative install CD " which will give you a text based installer, I could get it done without hiccups

http://releases.ubuntu.com/precise/